# Leer múltiples lectores de código de barras al mismo tiempo, en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo dos lectores de códigos de barras los cuales windows los detecta como teclados. Hay ocaciones en que están leyendo al mismo tiempo y la información se mezcla.

¿Como puedo hacer para que la información entregada pueda ser identificada y/o separada?

Comment: En principio no puedes, salvo que los lectores permitan configurar algun caracter que ingresen junto a la lectura que permita identificar cual dispositivo ejecuto la accion. Pero bueno esto depende del lector, quizas habra que ver el manual si lo permite o consultar al fabricante

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Asi como esta, no hay una respuesta a tu pregunta a menos que agregues mas informacion a la misma.